# Find path in graphs

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to learn python, and started few weeks back. I was reading about graphs today and found the below code:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, graph_dict=None):
        if graph_dict == None:
            graph_dict = {}
        self.__graph_dict = graph_dict

    def find_path(self, start_vertex, end_vertex, path=None):
        """Find a path from start_vertex to end_vertex in graph."""
        if path == None:
            path = []

        graph = self.__graph_dict
        print(self.__graph_dict)

        path = path + [start_vertex]
        if start_vertex == end_vertex:
            return path
        if start_vertex not in graph:
            return None
        for vertex in graph[start_vertex]:
            if vertex not in path:
                extended_path = self.find_path(vertex, end_vertex, path)
                if extended_path:
                    return extended_path
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = {"a" : ["c"],
         "b" : ["c", "e"],
         "c" : ["b", "d", "e"]}

    graph = Graph(g)

    graph.find_path("a", "d")
```

here i am not able to understand when i print 
`print(self.__graph_dict)` 
i get the below as print output:

```
{'a': ['c'], 'b': ['c', 'e'], 'c': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
{'a': ['c'], 'b': ['c', 'e'], 'c': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
{'a': ['c'], 'b': ['c', 'e'], 'c': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
{'a': ['c'], 'b': ['c', 'e'], 'c': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
{'a': ['c'], 'b': ['c', 'e'], 'c': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
```

What i am not able to understand why it is repeated 5 times and not just once which is the dictionary value of the graph. Does it have any significance also? Am i missing something here. Thanks in advance for valuable inputs and time.

Comment: After init, you haven't done anything to modify graph dict. Your first print statement will print exactly the graph dict. Also, the function doesn't ever modify the graph dictionary, so it never prints anything but the original

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the print out 5 times because you are recursively calling `find_path`.

See the code:

```
for vertex in graph[start_vertex]:
    if vertex not in path:
        extended_path = self.find_path(vertex, end_vertex, path) #this is being hit 4 times
```

I don't see that as an issue as far as your code working or not. It seems to make sense to me.

Comment: Also, you're printing _inside_ the `find_path` method, but it looks like you should have been printing only in the last line, when you call `graph.find_path`.